# Youtube javascript API and Android application in webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube-api

I use the youtube javascript API to autoplay my youtube video in an android application. (version 2.2 and later)
In my application I load this html in a webview. I use the same code in my IOS application.
With IOS it work. When I load my video, my video is playing automatically.

With Android when I load my html, my code is loadded, my video start to launch but it's never read.

When I desable autoplay and the user click on the video, it work !
And I have enable :  `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="player"></div>
 <script>
   var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
   var player;
   function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
     player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '150',
                       width: '300',
                       videoId: 'EW5w684bYFw',
                       events: {
                         'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                         'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                       }
              });
   }

   function onPlayerReady(event) {
     event.target.playVideo();
   }
   var done = false;

   function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
     if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
     //      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
       done = true;
     }
   }

   function stopVideo() {
     player.stopVideo();
   }
 </script>
</body>
```

Can you help me ?

edit : it work on android 2.2 galaxy s2 but not on galaxy s3 (android4.1)!

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same problem/question. Did you ever get this to work. If so, how?

Comment: I don't remind my solution. But I think I used the HTML5Webview.java class at this adress : http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/. Android 2.2 don't support HTML5